# Instantiating and Returning a C++ Wrapped Object using Node.js Add-on

Tags: node.js

I am using Node 0.12 and trying to create an addon.

I have two wrapped c++ classes, A and B.  In one of my methods in class A, I want to return a wrapped instance of B.  So, for example class A has the abbreviated interface shown below.  In the method Api of class A, I’d like to instantiate and return a class B wrapped object.  I tried working with `NewInstance()`, but wasn't sure how to call the constructor in the `NewInstance()` method I defined for class B.  Any help you might offer would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

-Jon

```
class A : public node::ObjectWrap {
public:
static void Init(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports);

private:
explicit A(Connection *connection);
~B();

static void New(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args);
static void Api(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args);

static v8::Persistent<v8::Function> constructor;

Connection* _connection;
};

#endif

class B : public node::ObjectWrap {
public:
static void Init(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports);


private:

~B();

static v8::Persistent<v8::Function> constructor;
// The method that will construct & return the new JavaScript object

Event* _event;
};

#endif
```

And here is what I attempted to do with `NewInstance()`:

```
void B::NewInstance(const v8::internal::Arguments& args) {
 Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
 HandleScope scope(isolate);

 const unsigned argc = 1;
 Local<Function> cons = Local<Function>::New(isolate, constructor);
 Local<Object> instance = cons->NewInstance(argc, argv);

 args.GetReturnValue().Set(instance);
}
```

Comment: 4 yrs later, i got the same issue with Nan api, on node>=8. A great example is available here with a module that implements `NewInstance` method [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples/tree/master/8_passing_wrapped/nan).